# how to encode special character using php function

Tags: php, sql, database

my orginal text is `1 1/2"w x 1/2"h` , but in database it look likes `1 1/2â€w x 1/2â€h`.

I am using stripslashes().

But still i can't convert the encrypted string.

Thank You all

i just added to html.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: stripslashes()? what for? What collation is your db and tables? That's not encryption, btw

Comment: What encoding is your database using?

Comment: but already i have insert so i don't want to change it, is there any php function

Comment: You're looking for the wrong answer. Changing the collation shouldn't affect your data and will show the proper character.

Comment: change your table charcter set to utf8_general_ci and try it!But i think you use invalid character for double queto !

Comment: Looks to me that you try to save an UTF-8 (multibyte) string into a ISO-8859-1 (singlebyte) database field. Do you convert the original text before writing it to the database, e.g. with `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $orgText)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you read you have to use `stripslashes()` to escape database input or output but that information is wrong. You always have to use the specific escaping mechanism provided by your database library. For instance, if you are using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) you can use [bindValue()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to inject values into your SQL code.

As about `1 1/2â€w x 1/2â€h`, that looks like a multi-byte UTF-8 string misinterpreted as some single-byte encoding (possibly ISO-8859-1). It looks like you are either trying to fit UTF-8 data into a Latin1 database or providing a wrong charset when connecting to the database. In the first case, the best solution is changing your DB charset to match your application's charset (if your DBMS allows to do so). In the second case, you'll probably find the solution in the [PHP manual page for whatever your DB library is](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php): look for some method to specify the charset or encoding of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try UTF-8 collation (utf8_general_ci) on your database, tables, and columns.

Comment: Where did you change the collation? At the database level? Table level? Column level?